# SpringSecurityFilterChain & Actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When i'm adding *spring-boot-starter-actuator* dependency to my pom.xml, i'm getting an exception **"Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'"**
Without it project compiles normaly.

```
15:52:49,448 [ERROR][host-startStop-1][.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/red_tst]] - Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.normalizePath(ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration$IgnoredPathsWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.java:129)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$afc86f48.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$5(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$afc86f48$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ead45fb9.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$afc86f48.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

My Spring Security config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AuthorizationService authService;
    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    MDCFilter instanceMDCFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .cacheControl().disable()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .sessionFixation()
                    .migrateSession()
                .and()   
                .addFilterAfter(instanceMDCFilter,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()              
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")  
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
                .and()
            .rememberMe()               
                .tokenValiditySeconds(604800)
                .and();
    }

    @Autowired
    Md5PasswordEncoder md5Encoder;
    @Bean 
     public Md5PasswordEncoder md5PasswordEncoder(){
         return new Md5PasswordEncoder();
  }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(authService)
            .passwordEncoder(md5Encoder);
    }   
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dependency-storage</id>
            <url>http:%url%/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>dependency-storage</id>
            <url>http:%url%</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <start-class>red.Application</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
          <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.artofsolving</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodconverter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.artofsolving</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodconverter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.livesense</groupId>
            <artifactId>jodconverter-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>name</finalName> 
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you provide your pom.xml or spring version?

Comment: @franDayz posted my pom.xml

Comment: Do you have any Controller implementing ErrorController? If yes, is the method getErrorPath() returning a valid path?

Comment: @franDayz yes, you are right, the proplem was with bad ErrorController implementetion. I temporary removed this implementation and application compiled with actuator. Please, give some explanation in seperate answer and i'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the exception by defining a Controller implementing ErrorController and making getErrorPath() return null:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/whatever")
    public String myMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "hello.html";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So maybe you are also implementing ErrorController with a wrong getErrorPath() method.